# ¿Cómo llamar dos tablas con un Stored Procedure?

Tags: postgresql

Necesito traer los datos de dos tablas que tengo en una BD de POSTGRESQL con un SP

Este es el código que tengo pero no muestra nada

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_reporte(f_codigo integer) RETURNS int AS $$

BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM facturacion f
                INNER JOIN dtfactura d ON f.codigo = d.codigo
                WHERE f.codigo = f_codigo;                                                       
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

¿Me podrían decir qué puedo hacer?

Además me manda este error

> la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero lo que muestras es una función, que es distinto a un PA no?

Comment: si, los dos son diferentes

Comment: Es que entonces si quieres un PA la sintaxis es [como esta](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html)

Comment: nesecito es traer los datos de las tablas, pero asi no me trae nada

Comment: pero requieres retornar el resultado de esa consulta completa?

Comment: si, quiero mostrar todo

Comment: entonces mira mi respuesra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas retornar el resultado de la consulta debes definir la funcion para soporte eso, en este caso de tipo TABLE o SETOF y agregarle el return query a la consulta para que la funcion sepa que retornar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_reporte(f_codigo integer) RETURNS TABLE (columna1 tipodato, columna2 tipodato...) AS $$

BEGIN
 return query SELECT * FROM facturacion f
                INNER JOIN dtfactura d ON f.codigo = d.codigo
                WHERE f.codigo = f_codigo;                                                       
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*columna1 tipodato, columna2 tipodato...*: deben ser todas las columnas  del resultado de tu consulta y deben coincidir los tipos de datos

y entonces llamarias a la funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
select * from sp_reporte(f_codigo integer);
```

Además para lograr estos resultados siempre debes usar funciones, pues los procedimientos (que estan desde PG 11) no lo permiten

Comment: ya me funciono. Muchas gracias!